# How to Complete entire line containing keyword

Tags: autocompletion

I have hidden buffers and I'd like to be able to get an import from another file to place into a file. For example, if I were to have this in another buffer:

```java
import javafx.controls.Button;
```

if I were to type `import`  and then do `<c-x>` `<c-n>` or `<c-x>` `<c-l>` I'd be able to get that line. But would it be possible for me to type in

```
Button
```

and then do a sequence to get matches for things that come before I type in `Button`? I suppose it's kind of a "reverse omni" or "line" completion.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you're looking for Java import help, you might be more interested in something like [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/).

Comment: @Zoe yes I've used coc in the past, it a bit finicky on my system when used with gradle/maven so I've just avoided it. Being able to do a "reverse" autofill would be pretty cool in other circumstances though, thanks though!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se], by the way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Actually junegunn already has everything covered for you. Since you already use fzf you can add this to your `vimrc`:

```
imap <c-x><c-l> <plug>(fzf-complete-line)
```

And now `<c-x><c-l>` will use fzf to fuzzy match your line against the existing one in your buffers and complete directly in your buffer.

See fzf's [readme](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#mappings) for the list of available completion functions.

---

One way to do it would to be leverage the `:Lines` function provided by [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/). This is probably a bit overkill if you don't already have the plugin in your workflow but if you, do you could add this mapping to your vimrc:

```
nnoremap <leader>i :execute('Lines ' . expand('<cWORD>'))<CR>
```

The mapping calls the `Lines` command with the WORD under your cursor as argument (see [`:h <cWORD>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3ccWORD%3e) and [`:h execute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#execute%28%29))

Then when you are in normal mode and your cursor is on `Button` you can use `<leader>i` (or any key you'll use in your mapping) and this will show this kind of window with the list of the lines in the open buffers matching the word under your cursor.

[image]

Fzf provides two related commands which could be useful here:

[image]

You could also make something using only built-in vim features but that requires a bit more work. A starting point would probably be to read [`:h 'grepprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27grepprg%27).

Comment: I actually have fzf in my workflow so this is very useful! I've used lines but now it's nice to enable it to use the word under the cursor.

Is it possible to input the line of that text to where my cursor is?

Comment: @joshpetit I'm not sure I completely understand, do you mean something like `:execute('Lines ' . getline('.'))`?

Comment: so for example I mean (this may need to be created in a function call I assume) but once you execute the original command with `<leader>i` and the search result is found with the import, how could we insert the line of text from the found import into the line we currently are on?

Comment: How right I didn't notice that hitting `Enter` on the window moves to the line instead of inserting it. A first, not ideal, idea would be to hit `Escape` to toggle normal mode and then yank the line as you'd do in a regular buffer, close the window and past the yanked line. But this is not very convenient. Let me see if I can find a better solution.

Comment: Turns out junegunn already thought of everything! See my edit I think it's the best solution with fzf.

Comment: Wow fzf is such a beauty. Seeing it work so nicely is so awesome! There's probably a lot more it can do, reading the help is going to be fun haha. Thanks a lot!

Comment: FZF can do a lot indeed! It's a shame that their documentation is (IMHO) so poor that doesn't help to discover all the features.